# Jenkins: how do I prevent a build when certain commits made to a git repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, polling

I'm running a Jenkins build pipeline that makes a version increment and commits/ pushes to a git repo. How do I prevent a new build taking place? I've recently updated to git plugin 3.5.1 and do no have a "ignore Polling..." option in project configuration. Are there any other plugins that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one plugin that I am aware of that will do this for you.  You can find it here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ci-skip-plugin

This allows you to added a message into the commit message to specify whether a build should be skipped or not.

For example, you could use the following commit message:

`documentation update [ci skip]`

More information can be found on the project readme:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ci-skip-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Once you have it installed, click on one of your jobs from the Jenkins homepage, then click on Configure (down the left hand side), click on the Build Environment tab, and then select the "Enable ci-skip" option.

i.e. this is a configuration that is applied on a per-job basis.

Comment: Thanks for this Gary. I've successfully installed ci skip and its dependencies, however I do not have the option to enable ci-skip on the job config GUI. So the functionality isn't working. We have updated Jenkins recently so this is probably the reason.

Comment: Are there any other plugins you know of that carry out this function?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only one that I am aware of.

Comment: I have just installed the ci-skip extension on Jenkins 2.77-1.1 and it seems to be working fine to me.  I can see the `Enable ci-skip` in the `Build Environment` configuration for my jobs.

Comment: How are you getting to build environment option? I'm presuming its -    master >> view configuration ....

Comment: I have updated answer with steps on how to configure.

Comment: Cheers for your help, but looks like the ci ckip option isn't available on multibranch pipline option which is what i'm trying to run.